# Apollo GraphQL Error: Query root type must be provided

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have an Angular/Apollo GraphQL implementation generating typescript code based on GraphQl endpoint which is surfacing a schema.  I can hit the endpoint via Postman with a query and results are returned.  However, when I run "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml" via npm I get this error:

"Error: Query root type must be provided"

The server side is .Net Core implementation using GraphQL ASPNetCore.  I have 4 different queries defined and each one works via graphiql.

Any ideas on why query root type is now being returned as null?

Comment: If it's an issue with the `graphql-codegen` command you're running, you should include the content of the `codegen.yml` in your question and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: graphql-codegen command has not changed from when the process was working.

Answer (score 8):

GraphQL must have at least one @Query() to be considered valid. So maybe only need add any Query to your Resolver code will be helpful.
Ex:

```
export class FooResolver {

  @Query(() => String)
  sayHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dung Le, you can ask for the examples code before answer a question in the future,  however I'm happy that you are interested to contributed for the community. Welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

This error throws when your schema stiching/definitions are incorrect. Please check the check your root schema definitions

https://www.advancedgraphql.com/content/schema-stitching

Comment: I've removed all but 1 query from my source code and am still getting 'Query root type must be provided'.  There should not be any stitching conflicts with a single query.

Comment: If possible can you please share your code. Can i have a look

Comment: "_when your schema stiching/definitions are incorrect._" -- or missing/there's no query exposing data at all. A GraphQL schema without a query is kind of like the sound of a tree falling in the woods with nobody around. Except GraphQL throws an error. (－‸ლ)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue while using `graphql-codegen`.

my codegen.yml is

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:3001/graphql"
documents: "src/app/graphql/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-apollo-angular
```

The issue was coming when I used the plugin `typescript-apollo-angular`.

I'm using `Nodejs` with `graphql` as backend.

The issue got resolved when I renamed the type 
RootQuery -> Query
and 
RootMutation -> Mutation
in backend **schema**.

Before

```
type RootQuery {
  _empty: String  
}

type RootMutation {
  _empty: String
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
    mutation: RootMutation
}
```

After

```
type Query {
  _empty: String  
}

type Mutation {
  _empty: String
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reverting back to a previous version of the codebase and reapplied my modifications manually and it works now.  The only thing I can think of is I ran npm update which updated apollo-angular from 1.8.3 to 1.10.0.

**EDIT**  Here is my code:

codegen.yml (used to generate code from npm command):

```
overwrite: true
schema: "https://to_end_point/Prod/api/v1/GraphQL"
documents: "src/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-apollo-angular"
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

After reverting back to a previous version of Angular code then re-applying my code modifications, GraphQl code generation worked again.  The only thing I can think of which could have caused this issue was when I ran npm update.  Below is a screenshot of before/after of package.json:

[image]